# exiting from script

Tags: bash, scripting, exit, aircrack-ng

I'm running aircrack-ng cmd  inside a simple  script

```
#! /bin/bash 
clear 
echo "enter router mac \n"
read mac 
echo "enter path to word list \n "
read list
echo "enter path to file contain handshake \n"
read handshake 
aircrack-ng -b $mac  -w $list  $handshake
```

when i press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>  script terminated but aircrack-ng still working.

i know it maybe simple but i'm new .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> you are sending a signal (SIGINT) to the job running in the foreground to be interrupted, such job is the script, not `aircrack-ng`.

What you can do though, is control how your script behaves when it receives SIGINT:

```
#! /bin/bash 

trap "pkill aircrack-ng && exit" SIGINT SIGTERM

clear 
echo "enter router mac \n"
read mac 
echo "enter path to word list \n "
read list
echo "enter path to file contain handshake \n"
read handshake 
aircrack-ng -b $mac  -w $list  $handshake
```